# Onmousedown on an element?

Tags: javascript

I am using jquery to select an element how do I add the onmousedown event to it and obtain data from the onmousedown parameter?

This is the code that I so far have.

```
$("#" + that.id).addEventListener(onmousedown(event), function(d) { alert("Hello")});
```

Comment: Read the documentation about [mousedown](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/)

Comment: I recommend to read the jQuery tutorial about event handling: https://learn.jquery.com/events/ . It will contain anything you need to know about binding event handlers. What you currently have is, unfortunately, completely wrong.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, please update your question and add the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Without jQuery:

**Using `.addEventListener` (recommended):**

```
document.getElementById(this.id).addEventListener("mousedown", function (event) {
    console.log(event);
});
```

**Or, using `.onmousedown`:**

```
document.getElementById(this.id).onmousedown(function (event) {
    console.log(event);
});
```

#### With jQuery:

**Using `.on` (recommended):**

```
$("#" + this.id).on("mousedown", function (event) {
    console.log(event);
});
```

**Or, using `.onmousedown`:**

```
$("#" + this.id).onmousedown(function (event) {
    console.log(event);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

try this,

```
$("#" + that.id).mousedown(function(e) { alert("Hello")});
```